# Vb.net: Send text to window via windows messages

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program with vb.net (VS2008) for studio shooting with my Nikon D600.
I'm using a program called ControlMyNikon for tethered shooting and it's working perfectly.
It has this external control-feature with following instructions: http://i.jjj.fi/a9dAQ7z.png

Could someone give me hint what does 'send string to 'ControlMyNikon v4.1' window with windows messages' actually mean?

I tried with SendMessages. 
I was able to change window title with WM_SETTEXT but that's all.
I'm able to get the window handle but don't know how to send any string to it.

Help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, Nikon is pretty infamous for writing truly crappy shovelware.  This does not disappoint.  Here are some declarations that ought to work.  Try the Unicode version first.  If that produces Chinese text then use the Ansi version:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Class NativeMethods
    Friend Const WM_SETTEXT As Integer = 12

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageW", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowTextUnicode(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SendMessageA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowTextAnsi(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
NativeMethods.SetWindowTextUnicode(handleYouFound, WM_SETTTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "shoot")
```

If neither works then you are probably using the wrong window handle.  Use Spy++ to double check that you located the window properly.